# How to get grep -m1 to work in OSX

Tags: linux, macos, bash, grep

I have a script which I used perfectly fine in Linux, but now that I've switched over to Mac, the script still runs but has slightly different behavior.

This is a script for tallying student attendance at departmental functions. We use a portable barcode scanner to scan their ID's, and then save all scans in one csv file per date.

I used `grep -m1 $ID csvfolder/* | wc -l`  in the past to get a count of how many files their ID shows up in. The -m1 is necessary to make sure they don't get "extra credit" for repeatedly scanning in at the same event.

However, when I use this same command in Mac, it exits grep when it has found the first match in the first file. So if the student shows up in 4 files, `wc -l` still returns 1

How can I (without installing the GNU versions) emulate this feature?

Comment: `grep -m1` on Mac stops after the first match in the first file that matches, rather than on the first match in each file that matches.  This is the sort of problem that standards avoid -- `-m` is not a standardized option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have Mac OS X handy to test it with, but the following is Posix-standard afaik:

```
grep -l "$ID" csvfolder/* | wc -l
```

The `grep` will print the name of each file which contains a match. That should work with Gnu grep equally.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use `awk` for this task:

```
awk -v id="$ID" '$0 ~ id{print 1; exit}' csvfolder/* | wc -l
```